# How many images per iteration in Detectron2

Tags: iteration, object-detection, detectron

I am new to using detectron2, just learning it.This might be a noob question, but I really need the answer. I find nothing related to number of epochs in the repository.

We know , epoch means single passing of all data through the model, and a batch means a certain subset of the whole dataset, that has the ability to impact the loss  through gradient descent.
In this model, (Detectron2) we have something called iteration. What does this iteration mean? Does it mean passing of one batch through the mode, or an epoch(that shouldn't be the case considering time per iteration)

My question is , how do I know the minimum number of iterations that will pass all my images to the model, at least once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In detectron2, `epoch` is  `MAX_ITER * BATCH_SIZE / TOTAL_NUM_IMAGES`

Comment: you mean every iteration passes one batch?

Comment: Yes. You got it. To understand these you can run `plain_train_net.py` from tools folder and print file names from the training loop.

Comment: @Sawradip, If you find my answer is useful, then click on the useful button. It will help others.

Comment: How do i pass the batch_size? Currently, my implementation is running out of memory, I'm not able to figure out why

Answer (score 8):

I don't think the currently accepted answer is correct

```
single_iteration = cfg.SOLVER.NUM_GPUS * cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH
```

therefore, if you want to now how many iterations you need for an epoch (all images seen once), that number would be

```
iterations_for_one_epoch = TOTAL_NUM_IMAGES / single_iteration
```

So if you want to train for 20 epochs, you would set MAX_ITER as follows:

```
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = iterations_for_one_epoch * 20
```

Sources:

[Detectron2 Docs](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/detectron2/engine/train_loop.html?highlight=iteration#) (one iteration is one run_step-call, and that pulls one "datapoint" from the loader data = next(self._data_loader_iter))

[MaskRCNN-benchmark Github issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/issues/184) explains it in a similar way

Comment: I think the equation is wrong because when I set IMS_PER_BATCH=2  and NUM_GPUS =8, it shell terminal shows an error message that 2/8 isn't divisible. 
########################################################

single_iteration = cfg.SOLVER.NUM_GPUS * cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH
########################################################

Comment: Agreed with @yuhang.tao, cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH is the number of training images per iteration. If you run detectron2 on multi GPUs, the number of images per GPU is calculated accordingly. i.e. SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH/# of GPUs. See official definition here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/9725c7f2150c985e601301789e6568603c8ca1f6/detectron2/config/defaults.py#L556

Answer (score -4):

According to [this](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/_modules/detectron2/engine/train_loop.html?highlight=iteration#) source code, iteration in Detectron2 terminology equals `epoch`.
You should find optimal `MAX_ITER` value experimentally by selection optimal loss rate/train time ratio.